# Redirect some pages to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess

First I directed my /example folder to main domain. Now, I'd like to redirect some of the pages to HTTPS. Pls, anyone could advice me about the code:

```
# com upload yonlendirme
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example/index.php [L]

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com (or any other subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#force https for certain pages    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(index\.php?route=account/register|index\.php?route=account/login|index\.php?route=account/account|index\.php?route=checkout/checkout)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}[L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?`) in a rewrite rule. You'll need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=(account/register|account/login|account/account|checkout/checkout)
RewriteRule ^index.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}[L,R]
```

You may also want to move that rule up to the top of your htaccess file so the routing to the `example` folder doesn't interfere with the redirects.

Comment: It is still not working. I put it to the top. Is it because the whole page working in the /example folder?

Comment: do you have any idea?